# String inside two strings in a pattern

Tags: r, regex

```
text <-"screenname volpeusdot name volpe usdot id 3084605733 screenname meijer name meijer id 14277701 screenname mndot name minnesota department of transportation id 163876555"

gsub(".*screenname (.+) name.*","\\1", text)
```

It generates:

```
"mndot"
```

However, I want to get like the following:

```
"volpeusdot meijer mndot"
```

Comment: Please post code that doesn't fail with `Error in gsub(".*screenname (.+) name.*", text) : 
  argument "x" is missing, with no default

Comment: Also, tag regex questions [tag:regex] so you get a faster answer (a lot of regex stuff is language-agnostic, so you get 100x the eyeballs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a solution with the tidyverse:

```r
library(stringr)
text <-"screenname volpeusdot name volpe usdot id 3084605733 screenname meijer name meijer id 14277701 screenname mndot name minnesota department of transportation id 163876555"
"volpeusdot meijer mndot"
#> [1] "volpeusdot meijer mndot"
stringr::str_extract_all(text, regex("(?<=screenname\\s)[:alpha:]*\\b"))
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "volpeusdot" "meijer"     "mndot"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-12-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

A base R option using `regmatches`

```
> regmatches(text, gregexpr("(?<=screenname\\s)\\w+", text, perl = TRUE))
[[1]]
[1] "volpeusdot" "meijer"     "mndot"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ex_between_multiple` from `qdapRegex` to extract a string between two words.

```
trimws(as.character(qdapRegex::ex_between_multiple(text, 'screenname ', 'name')))
#[1] "volpeusdot" "meijer"     "mndot"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really are after getting a single string as a result use

```r
library(stringr)
text <-"screenname volpeusdot name volpe usdot id 3084605733 screenname meijer name meijer id 14277701 screenname mndot name minnesota department of transportation id 163876555"
paste(str_extract_all(text, "(?<=screenname\\s).*?(?=\\sname)")[[1]], collapse=" ")
```

**Results**: `[1] "volpeusdot meijer mndot"`

See [R proof](https://tio.run/##VU/RTsMwDHzfV1h5atBALV2bPazqh2zTZFozBaVO5BgEX19akNh4uzud73wyz8G/CMpXkVU8X8VulD4VDo8mD0LEjBPBRwyJ3vMYFW4cfgU/Ql3ud23ZuLqGu6OJ/BsJ3OPFW@2enXNl9c/Jf8mTZ6YcFWGkhKITsUJ8BRXknKIoqo/8E9TWe9c2TWM2CbPSOuCyvC446AVDKNYdWzBFf@huXadTtk8PfdF3C1oFa@zxWJ3PWxhiCJgydQaMnedv) and the [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/GD9YAo/1).

**Expression explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<=                     look behind to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    screenname               'screenname'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the least amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    name                     'name'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```